# Static code analysis - Dependence map of Cobol.Net program

Tags: static-analysis, microfocus, cobol.net

We have some Microfocus Cobol.Net applications.

We would like to create a dependency map similar to what is available in NDepend.

Does anyone know of a tool that is able to do this?

Comment: Do you have specific questions you want to ask of the COBOL code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not knowledgeable on Cobol .NET but I am a programmer of NDepend. If Cobol .NET emits valid .NET assemblies, then NDepend can analyze them, since NDepend can analyze any .NET assembly.

Comment: Interesting.  Does it produce sensible numbers for F#?

Comment: F# compile to IL. There is a lot of work done by the F# compiler to transform the F# functional syntax stuff into the IL OOP-alike stuff. With NDepend you'll get info about this IL OOP-alike stuff. It'll certainly help assess things like code size, complexity, dependency, diff... but not as much as with C# or VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks, some info was missing like the Lines of Code, apart from that it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

Off the shelf, I'd guess the closest you would come is MicroFocus's Revolve tool.

It is intended to let you explore your application interactively, and I think it does metrics.   I don't know if it constructs a "static map" you can explore offline.  Nor do I believe it has the level of programmability of NDepend.